# Handling the selection of Cancel in iOS 7 native login popup

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am writing some in-app purchase related code. When I initiate the in-app purchase, iOS pops up a native login popup as shown in the image below. I am also starting to animate a 
UIActivityIndicatorView. If the user selects the Cancel option, I want to stop animating the UIActivityIndicatorView. What is the way to handle the selection of Cancel in iOS 7 native login popup.

[image: iOS 7 native login popup]

The following function is not being called:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate for the UIAlertView....

Comment: I guess for system generated `UIAlertView` we are not able to received  any delegate call.

Comment: @IronManGill But, this popup comes from the system. I am not showing the UIAlertView here. If I need to explicitly set the delegate, can you tell me how to do that? The code that is invoking this popup is `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
> ```

above method get called when user presses cancel on restore alert.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When user presses the cancel button SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed get called, 
**NOTE:** This is not always the case, this also get called for some other response also

Comment: I just checked and found that `-paymentQueue` does not get called if the user selects Cancel. Can you check and again and confirm?

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the right answer!

`-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`